# post id not displaying

Tags: sql

I have used this code in header.php

```
### get the author info
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$authorid = $current_user->ID;
### get the last post id using author id
$info=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $authorid ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
$array_content = mysql_fetch_array( $info );
$postid_profile = $array_content['ID'];
```

When i print the $postid_profile in header.php it displays correctly. But if i print the `$postid_profile` in single.php it displays nothing. I couldn't track the error. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your header.php file by calling `get_header()` function in single.php file. It means that your `$postid_profile` variable exists only in scope of `get_header()` function. To make it visible in global scope you need to make your variable global.

So your code should be modified like this:

```
### get the author info
global $current_user, $postid_profile;
get_currentuserinfo();
$authorid = $current_user->ID;
### get the last post id using author id
$info=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $authorid ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
$array_content = mysql_fetch_array( $info );
$postid_profile = $array_content['ID'];
```

Now your `$postid_profile` variable will exist in global scope and will be accessible in single.php file.

As additional I would strongly recommend you to use `$wpdb` variable to perform all db queries calls. Plus to get current user id you can use `get_current_user_id()` function. So your code should be like this:

```
### get the author info
global $postid_profile;
get_currentuserinfo();
$authorid = get_current_user_id();
### get the last post id using author id
$array_content = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $authorid ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
$postid_profile = $array_content['ID'];
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks for your detailed answer.